# Background image with Bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, twitter-bootstrap, background

I have a issue that it driving me nuts. I am beginning to learn RoR and I dont know why I can't set up a background image on my Bootstrap 3 app. I tried everything, but the the image doesn't "load".

I used this site to do this: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

What could be doing wrong?

** If I change html to body, nothing happens. Same thing if I remove the quotes or not.

Thanks in advance!

> UPDATE: **Sorry. Newb error. The image was damaged. There was the
>   problem. Thanks for all help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>

     <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<style>

html { 
      background: url('images/fondo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>


</head>
      <body>



        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The funny thing is if I use any URL image like voices.suntimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/…, all works fine. The problem is with the images that are on my pc

Comment: yes @philip7899, rails!

Comment: and all my images are in the app/assets/images directory. @Philip7899

Comment: Did you put your stylesheet in the stylesheet directory?  When you do, make sure to remove the style tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Philip7899. Yes, I put it in the app/assets/stylesheets/application.css too. Mi doubt is about Bootstrap, because its priority before others stylesheet right? Maybe I should put the stylesheet into the bootstrap.css/bootstrap.min.css directory too?

Comment: Ahh, take it out of application.css.  Make a new file in the stylesheet folder called master.css.scss .  You should not touch the application.css file for now.  I don't think you need to put it in the bootstrap css files either.

Comment: Done, the master folder was created and I pasted the stylesheet code without tags. What should I do now? @Philip7899

Comment: Would have something to do the fact that I'm using "scaffold". I asking because exists scaffolds.css.sccs too. @Philip7899

Comment: Hey, although I don't think it should make a difference, there should not be a master folder, just a master file in the assets folder.  Scaffolding shouldn't make a difference.  Where is the file you posted in your rails directory?

Comment: Aaah, ok. Look my github: https://github.com/efromm/mediaGO @Philip7899!

Comment: The funny thing is if I use any URL image like http://voices.suntimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Cookiemonster2_FB.jpg, all works fine.
The problem is with the images that are on my pc.

Comment: You have no quotes around your image url.  Also, don't put it in the application.css file.  Like I said, make a new file called master.css.  Just making a master.css file in the assets directory will have it automatically pulled to your main page.

Comment: Also, the path is wrong.  it should be '/assets/Arsobispo.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

try

```
background: url('images/fondo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

I think the quotes will make a difference.

Also, your second style tag is missing the closing slash.  it should be:

```
</style>
```

If those don't work, also try replacing

```
html {
```

with

```
body {
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are using rails, you are setting up your application incorrectly.

In the apps/assets/stylesheets directory, you should put the stylesheet.  Your images should be in the images folder in the assets directory.  You should then refer to all images like

```
background: url('/assets/fondo.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

It can be tricky at first to get the hang of rails.